# How can I do a query with the help of typeorm Operators

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have done the following query with the help of `QueryBuilder`

```
let query = await this._categoryRepository.createQueryBuilder("categories")
if (filter.caption) {
    query = query.where(new Brackets(qb => {
        qb.where(`categories.captionFa LIKE :captionFa`, { captionFa: `%${filter.caption}%` });
        qb.orWhere(`categories.captionEn LIKE :captionEn`, { captionEn: `%${filter.caption}%` })
    }))
}
if (filter.isActive)
    query = query.andWhere('categories.isActive = :isActive', { isActive: filter.isActive })
const { 0: categories, 1: count } = await query.getManyAndCount()
```

How to use `Brackets()` in typeorm Operators....

```
const { 0: categories, 1: count } = await this._categoryRepository.findAndCount({
    where:{
       isActive:filter.isActive
    }
   // Here ...
})
```